Problem with i3 layouts not being attached to the right workspace
I have a working layout setup in i3 and am trying to attach it with this line on startup:
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg "workspace $utilities; append_layout /home/lucienfradet/.config/i3/layout/utilities_layout.json"
This is my whole config:
# i3 config file (v4)
#
# Please see http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!

# windows button is mod
set $mod Mod1

#set $term i3-sensible-terminal
# set $term gnome-terminal
set $term alacritty

# Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
# is used in the bar {} block below.
# This font is widely installed, provides lots of unicode glyphs, right-to-left
# text rendering and scalability on retina/hidpi displays (thanks to pango).
#font pango:Monospace 5
# use Pop OS standard font
font pango:Fira Sans 11


# mouse_warping moves mouse to center of window that takes focus (annoying)
mouse_warping none

focus_on_window_activation none

# possibly force to move to urgent window?
#force_display_urgency_hint 0 ms
#focus_on_window_activation urgent

# Make the currently focused window a scratchpad
bindsym $mod+Shift+BackSpace move scratchpad

# Show the first scratchpad window
bindsym $mod+backslash scratchpad show

# Use Mouse+$mod to drag floating windows to their wanted position
floating_modifier $mod

# Reminder: right-click mouse and drag on titlebar resizes a floating window
floating_minimum_size 150 x 150
floating_maximum_size 2500 x 1500

# start a terminal
bindsym $mod+Return exec $term

# start dmenu (rofi)
bindsym $mod+d exec rofi -show combi -combi-modi drun
# an "alt-tab" which shows window list
bindsym $mod+Tab exec rofi -show window

# kill focused window
bindsym $mod+Shift+q kill

# change focus (tweaked from defaults to be more VIM-like)
bindsym $mod+h focus left
bindsym $mod+j focus down
bindsym $mod+k focus up
bindsym $mod+l focus right

# move to monitor (tweaked from defaults to be more VIM-like)
bindsym $mod+Control+Shift+Up move workspace to output up
bindsym $mod+Control+Shift+Down move workspace to output down
bindsym $mod+Control+Shift+k move workspace to output up
bindsym $mod+Control+Shift+j move workspace to output down

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym $mod+Left focus left
bindsym $mod+Down focus down
bindsym $mod+Up focus up
bindsym $mod+Right focus right

# move focused window (tweaked from defaults to be more VIM-like)
bindsym $mod+Shift+h move left
bindsym $mod+Shift+j move down
bindsym $mod+Shift+k move up
bindsym $mod+Shift+l move right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym $mod+Shift+Left move left
bindsym $mod+Shift+Down move down
bindsym $mod+Shift+Up move up
bindsym $mod+Shift+Right move right

# -------- gaps ---------
set $gap 3
set $negativeGap -3
# Configure 5px of space between windows and to the screen edges.
gaps inner $gap

# Configure an additional 5px of extra space to the screen edges,
# for a total gap of 10px to the screen edges, and 5px between windows.
gaps outer $negativeGap

# Only enable outer gaps when there is exactly one window or split container on the workspace.
smart_gaps on

default_border normal 0

# split in horizontal orientation (adds Control, due to our VIM-like tweak)
bindsym $mod+Control+h split h

# split in vertical orientation (adds Control to match horizontal)
bindsym $mod+Control+v split v

# enter fullscreen mode for the focused container
bindsym $mod+f fullscreen toggle

# change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
bindsym $mod+s layout stacking
bindsym $mod+w layout tabbed
bindsym $mod+e layout toggle split

# toggle tiling / floating
bindsym $mod+Mod4+space floating toggle

# I don't seem to need this much, I use the mouse :(
# change focus between tiling / floating windows
bindsym $mod+space focus mode_toggle

# focus the parent container
bindsym $mod+a focus parent

# focus the child container
bindsym $mod+z focus child

# Named workspaces
set $ws1 1
set $ws2 2
set $ws3 3
set $ws4 4
set $ws5 5
set $ws6 6
set $ws7 7
set $ws8 8
set $ws9 9
set $ws0 0

set $utilities "1: utilities"
set $web "2: web"
set $workspace "3: workspace"
set $file_manager "4: files"
set $documents "5: documents"
set $other "6: other"
set $communication "0: communication"

# Layout
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg "workspace $utilities; append_layout /home/lucienfradet/.config/i3/layout/utilities_layout.json"
# bindsym $mod+u exec --no-startup-id i3-msg "workspace $utilities; append_layout /home/lucienfradet/.config/i3/layout/utilities_layout.json"

# keep certain workspaces on laptop display (does nothing if you don't have eDP-1)
workspace "$ws2" output eDP-1
workspace "$ws9" output eDP-1
workspace "$ws0" output eDP-1

bindsym $mod+1 workspace $utilities
bindsym $mod+2 workspace $web
bindsym $mod+3 workspace $workspace
bindsym $mod+4 workspace $file_manager
bindsym $mod+5 workspace $documents
bindsym $mod+6 workspace $other
bindsym $mod+0 workspace $communication

bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace $utilities
bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace $web
bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace $workspace
bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace $file_manager
bindsym $mod+Shift+5 move container to workspace $documents
bindsym $mod+Shift+6 move container to workspace $other
bindsym $mod+Shift+0 move container to workspace $communication

workspace_auto_back_and_forth yes

# assign [class="Bitwarden" instance="bitwarden"] $utilities
# assign [class="Gnome-terminal" instance="gnome-terminal-server"] $utilities
# assign [class="shortwave" instance="shortwave"] $utilities
# assign [class="strawberry" instance="strawberry"] $utilities
assign [class="Brave-browser" instance="brave-browser"] $web
assign [class="Org.gnome.Nautilus" instance="org.gnome.Nautilus"] $file_manager
assign [class="okular" instance="okular-bin"] $documents
assign [class="okular" instance="okular"] $documents
assign [class="libreoffice-writer" instance="libreoffice"] $documents


# switch to workspace
# bindsym $mod+1 workspace number $ws1
# bindsym $mod+2 workspace number $ws2
# bindsym $mod+3 workspace number $ws3
# bindsym $mod+4 workspace number $ws4
# bindsym $mod+5 workspace number $ws5
# bindsym $mod+6 workspace number $ws6
bindsym $mod+7 workspace number $ws7
bindsym $mod+8 workspace number $ws8
bindsym $mod+9 workspace number $ws9
# bindsym $mod+0 workspace number $ws0

# move focused container to workspace
# bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace number $ws1
# bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace number $ws2
# bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace number $ws3
# bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace number $ws4
# bindsym $mod+Shift+5 move container to workspace number $ws5
# bindsym $mod+Shift+6 move container to workspace number $ws6
bindsym $mod+Shift+7 move container to workspace number $ws7
bindsym $mod+Shift+8 move container to workspace number $ws8
bindsym $mod+Shift+9 move container to workspace number $ws9
# bindsym $mod+Shift+0 move container to workspace number $ws0

# reload the configuration file
bindsym $mod+Shift+c reload
# restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
bindsym $mod+Shift+r restart

# exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
# this is an i3 default and good to have, but using Gnome, we can Control+Alt+Delete to lock screen or logout
# bindsym $mod+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -B 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"

set $i3lockwall sh /home/lucienfradet/.config/i3/scripts/lock.sh

# shutdown / restart / suspend...
set $mode_system System (l) lock, (e) logout, (s) suspend, (h) hibernate, (r) reboot, (CTRL+s) shutdown

mode "$mode_system" {
    bindsym l exec --no-startup-id $i3lockwall, mode "default"
    bindsym e exec --no-startup-id i3-msg exit, mode "default"
    bindsym s exec --no-startup-id $i3lockwall && systemctl suspend, mode "default"
    bindsym h exec --no-startup-id $i3lockwall && systemctl hibernate, mode "default"
    bindsym r exec --no-startup-id systemctl reboot, mode "default"
    bindsym Ctrl+s exec --no-startup-id systemctl poweroff -i, mode "default"

    # back to normal: Enter or Escape
    bindsym Return mode "default"
    bindsym Escape mode "default"
}

bindsym $mod+BackSpace mode "$mode_system"

# diodon clipboard manager shortcut
bindsym $mod+p exec --no-startup-id /usr/bin/diodon

# nordvpn connection toggle
bindsym $mod+v exec --no-startup-id "nordvpn status | grep 'Status: Connected' && nordvpn disconnect || nordvpn connect"

# bind night light
bindsym $mod+n exec --no-startup-id /home/lucienfradet/.config/i3/scripts/night_light_toggle.sh

# resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
mode "resize" {
        # These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode

        # Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
        # Pressing right will grow the window’s width.
        # Pressing up will shrink the window’s height.
        # Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
    # (tweaked from defaults to be more VIM-like)
        bindsym h resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym j resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym k resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym l resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # same bindings, but for the arrow keys
        bindsym Left resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Down resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Up resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Right resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # back to normal: Enter or Escape
        bindsym Return mode "default";
        bindsym Escape mode "default";
}

bindsym $mod+r mode "resize";

# Applications behaving as "pop ups" are set to be always floating
#  i.e. popup, do stuff, close
# To get WM_CLASS and WM_TITLE values, on X run "xprop"

# settings apps
for_window [class="Gnome-tweaks"] floating enable
for_window [class="Gnome-control-center"] floating enable
for_window [class="Io.elementary.appcenter"] floating enable
for_window [class="Gnome-calculator"] floating enable
for_window [class="qt5ct"] floating enable
for_window [class="Synergy"] floating enable

# spotify, plexamp assigned to workspace and float plexamp
# assign [class="^Spotify"] $utilities
assign [class="^Plexamp"] $ws9
for_window [class="^Plexamp"] floating enable

# communication apps workspace assigned
assign [class="^discord"] $communication
assign [class="^rambox"] $communication
assign [class="^Slack"] $communication
assign [class="^Signal"] $communication
assign [class="^TelegramDesktop"] $communication

# skype, wine, gimp, etc are happier if floating
for_window [class="Gimp"] floating enable
for_window [class="Skype"] floating enable
for_window [class="zoom"] floating enable
for_window [class="Nxplayer.bin"] floating enable
for_window [class="Virt-manager"] floating enable
for_window [class="Virt-viewer"] floating enable
for_window [class="vlc"] floating enable
for_window [class="Wine"] floating enable
for_window [class="Pavucontrol"] floating enable

# games 
for_window [class="Moonlight"] floating enable
for_window [class="minecraft-launcher"] floating enable
for_window [class="^Minecraft*"] floating enable
for_window [class="Steam"] floating enable
# note: some games want to toggle fullscreen to be able to return to game, or use borderless windowed mode
for_window [class="^steam_app*"] floating enable


# auto run commands

# sometimes was needed to fix issues with some apps starting (like telegram)
#exec --no-startup-id dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

# start picom compositor
exec --no-startup-id picom -b

# notifications
# Pop OS `i3` package installed dunst, but it can be disabled like this for gnome notifications
# I've included dunst config though
#exec --no-startup-id bash -c "systemctl --user disable --now dunst"


# gnome integration
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
exec --no-startup-id gnome-flashback

# personal execs
#exec --no-startup-id pasystray # this is started by gnome-flashback by default
#exec --no-startup-id blueman-applet # this is started by gnome-flashback by default
exec --no-startup-id nm-applet

# set background to a Pop OS! background we can choose to match Gnome
exec --no-startup-id feh --bg-fill /home/lucienfradet/Pictures/Wallpapers/DesktopBack.png

# keyboard layout attempt
# Set initial keyboard layout
exec --no-startup-id setxkbmap -layout us
# Toggle between layouts using Mod (Windows key) + Shift + Space
bindsym $mod+Shift+space exec /home/lucienfradet/.config/i3/scripts/toggle_keyboard_layout.sh

for_window [class="Arandr"] floating enable

# use i3 bar with gnome

bindsym $mod+Shift+b bar mode toggle

# i3status bar config 
# font by default pulls from top-level above

set $selected #689D6A
set $focused #4c443c
set $grey #928374

bar {
  status_command i3status --config /home/lucienfradet/.config/i3/i3status.conf
  position bottom
  mode hide
  modifier Mod1
  i3bar_command i3bar --transparency
  # tray output on laptop screen, primary screen, or remove line for i3's pick
  #tray_output eDP-1
  #tray_output primary

  # pop-dark bar theme
  colors { 
    background #3F3B3995
    statusline #cccccc
    separator  #BE7704

    focused_workspace  $grey $selected #F6F6F6
    active_workspace   $grey #4C4845 #F6F6F6
    inactive_workspace $grey #4C4845 #cccccc
    urgent_workspace   #A00000 #900000 #cccccc
  }
}

# pop-dark theme
client.focused           $focused $focused #F6F6F6    $focused       $focused
client.focused_inactive  #353535  #353535  #cccccc    #353535        #353535
client.unfocused         #353535  #353535  #cccccc    #353535        #353535
client.urgent            #900000  #900000  #cccccc    #900000        #900000 
client.placeholder       #383838  #383838  #cccccc    #383838        #383838
client.background        #e0e0e0


It get's attached to $web for some reason. I tried attaching it to $ws1 as a test and that worked fine... I suspect there is a conflicting parameter in my config but can't find what. Or maybe I call it too soon or too late in my file?
Appreciate any help :)
